# css dropdown menu doesn't stay visible

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, hover, html-lists

CSS Dropdown menu does not stay `visible` on `mouseover`. I tried searching the answers but no codes work thus far. Here is the url: http://delawaresign.com.previewc40.carrierzone.com/about.html

but here's the clincher. It works FINE on another URL i made with the same flipping code!
http://delawaresign.com.previewc40.carrierzone.com/index-01-14-13.html

I can't figures this out! Why will it work on one but not the other??

It "shows" `visible`, but doesn't "stay" `visible`.

Comment: In which item the dropdown menu doesn't work?

Comment: @WilliamSeitiMizuta When you hover on the dropdown parts, they dont stay down, they disappear as soon as you try to hover over them

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a space between the menu item and drop down list. Put the drop down in other color and you will see the space.

The easiest solution to this is to remove this space putting the list up. Try to change the `top: 2.5em` to `top: 1.5em` in `.sf-menu li:hover ul` which is `inside superfish.css` file:

```
.sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
    left: 0;
    top: 1.5em;
    z-index: 99;
}
```